# PHP Parse Comma Separated String with double quotes

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv

I have a url parameter named data that contains a comma separated string with some enclosed in double quotes like this:

```
localhost/index.php?data=val1,val2,val3,"val4","val5",val6
```

I am trying to parse the string and put it into an array. Using `str_getcsv($_GET['data'],',','"');` gives me the output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => val1
    [1] => val2
    [2] => val3
    [3] => 
)
```

I would like the array to look like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => val1
    [1] => val2
    [2] => val3
    [3] => val4
    [4] => val5
    [5] => val6
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works fine for me. What does `var_dump($_GET['data'])` show?

Comment: urlencode the double quotes when generating that url –Because `<a href="localhost/index.php?data=val1,val2,val3,"val4","val5",val6">link</a>` will result in the url you go to only being `localhost/index.php?data=val1,val2,val3,`

Comment: He could also use single quotes around the `href` attribute.

Comment: @developerwjk Post it as an answer

Comment: This is a web service so its not coming from a `href`, it is just being called from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say urlencode the double quotes when generating that url. Because `<a href="localhost/index.php?data=val1,val2,val3,"val4","val5",val6">link</a>` will result in the url you go to only being `localhost/index.php?data=val1,val2,val3,`

So like:

```
echo '<a href="localhost/index.php?data=' . urlencode('val1,val2,val3,"val4","val5",val6') . '">link</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [explode](http://php.net/explode)? It'll separate a string into an array using whatever separator you specify.

Using your example,

```
$_GET['data'] = 'val1,val2,val3,"val4","val5",val6';
$testarr = explode(",", $_GET['data']);

var_dump($testarr);
```

Outputs:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "val1"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "val2"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "val3"
  [3]=>
  string(6) ""val4""
  [4]=>
  string(6) ""val5""
  [5]=>
  string(4) "val6"
}
```

Looking at your question again, it seems you might want to remove the `"` from $_GET['data'] entirely?. If so, do this:

```
$testarr = explode(",", str_replace('"','',$_GET['data']));
```